# Scroll and ValueChanged event on C# .NET TrackBar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, trackbar

IS there a way to capture all the values of trackbar while sliding the scroll? Scroll and ValueChanged event are working good in moderate speed. However if i scroll the slider fast, some values are skipped. For example if the values of the trackbar are from 0-26, using ValueChanged and Scroll event on moderate scrolling will capture all the values from 0-26. However when i scrolled the trackbar very fast. Captured values are only : 1,3,5,10,15,16,18,20,25,26. Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you

Comment: why do you need the values in the middle?

Comment: I am planning to use the values in the middle for zoom functionality

Comment: maybe the use don't care about the size in the middle

Comment: Ok surely. I am just wondering if this is expected. Thank you